# golang dep update source field in Gopkg.toml

Tags: go, vendor, dep

I add a line into `Gopkg.toml` that is `source="github.com/xxxx/xxxx"`. then call `dep ensure -update`. but the old dir still in vendor, it not work by add source into `Gopkg.toml`.

how to do it?

Comment: You can add a dependency by using `dep ensure -add github.com/xxx/xxx`.

Comment: sorry.  I make a mistake. `dep ensure -update` work fine when I add source line with exist pkg in `Gopkg.toml`. it will not broken current path, but it put new code in   that dir. it's good!

Comment: try delele Gopkg.lock file